# cannot convert from string to system.windows.forms.string iwin32window

Tags: c#

This is supposed to show the winner in the xWinner form label but I cant figure it out. 
xWinnerForm.Show(b1.Text);. I'm new to c# so can you please explain in layman terms thanks.

```
       static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
    {
        bool gameOver = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            int a = Winners[i, 0];
            int b = Winners[i, 1];
            int c = Winners[i, 2];

            Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
            if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
                continue;
            if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
            {
               gameOver = true;

                Form xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
                xWinnerForm.Show(b1.Text);


            }


    public void Show(string text)
    {
        this.xWinnerLabel.Text = text;
        this.Show();
    }

        }
        return gameOver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the smallest change you need to make it work:

```
xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
```

Though I'd suggest a few changes in addition to this:

- Use PascalCase for class names, but do use camel case for the variable name.

`XWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new XWinnerForm();`

- Don't overload `Show` in this manner. Instead change the constructor of your form to accept the extra data, or else add a setter to your form.

`XWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new XWinnerForm(b1.Text);`

- Don't use names like `a, b, c, b1`:

`XWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new XWinnerForm(labelWinner.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Currently the variable (`xWinnerForm`) is typed as `Form`, and `Form` has a `Show` method with a different signature. Instead, tell it which specific *type* of `Form` it is - a `WinnerForm` perhaps (your class name...). Or use a different method name (`Show` is going to cause confusion).

Answer (score 0):

```
Form xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
```

This line is your problem. Because you're declaring your variable as a `Form`, the compiler does not know about your `Show(string)` function.

As an aside, it's generally bad form to use a variable name that's the same as its type.

Instead, do something like this:

```
xWinnerForm winner = new xWinnerForm();

winner.Show(b1.Text);
```